# Oracle 19c - The Server tab is missing in Enterprise Manager

Tags: oracle-database

I installed Oracle 19c database. 
I logged as System user into Enterprise Manager.
I want to create new user and set permissions to him, but the Server tab is missing. There is only Performance tab.
[image]

Can you help me, please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Enterprise Manager Database Express which is delivered with Oracle Database 19c is based on Oracle JET (Javascript-Extension-Toolkit) and provides performance-reporting functionality only.
So it is intended that there is no server-tab.

You can revert back to the flash-based Enterprise Manager Database Express which was delivered with Oracle 12.1 to 18c with the SQL command (as SYS)
@?/rdbms/admin/execemx emx

Re-enabling the JET-based is done with @?/rdbms/admin/execemx omx

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admqs/getting-started-with-database-administration.html#GUID-BA75AD46-D22E-4914-A31E-C395CD6A2BBA

Comment: Hi @MJW
Now, when flash was removed from web browsers and I re-enabled JET.
How can I see Server tab, please ?

Comment: Hi, @miracle173
Now, when flash was removed from web browsers and I re-enabled JET.
How can I see Server tab, please ?